# How represente the curl command using the HttpPost: curl --form "tag=mytag" --form "archive=@test.pdf;type=application/pdf"

Tags: java, json, http, curl, http-post

How represente the curl command using the HttpPost:

```
curl --form "tag=mytag"  --form "archive=@c:/etc/test.pdf;type=application/pdf" ...
```

Below is my code:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(www.resourceURL.com);
httpPost.setHeader(Authorization: bearer cb084803-ba48-xxxx-xxxx-2a275e199c38)
....
```

below is the code I've done:
But i receive the HTTP 500 error

```
    List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(resourceURL);
    httpPost.setHeader(OAuthConstants.AUTHORIZATION, bearer cb084803-ba48-xxx-xxx-2a275xxx99c38 ));
    httpPost.setHeader(OAuthConstants.CONTENTE_TYPE, OAuthConstants.ENCODED_CONTENT_DATA);
    httpPost.setHeader(OAuthConstants.PARTNERUSERID, login);
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", doc.getTitre()));
    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", doc.getTag()));
    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("archive", "@" + doc.getPath() + ";type=application/pdf"));
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = null;
        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

I do not know how to solve this problem

I check content the contenet of response and i have this result:

```
[{"error":"bad_request","error_description":"malformed Json : Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `UrlEncodedFormEntity` and add your form elements there

```
List<NameValuePair> formEntries = new ArrayList<>(); // or whatever List sub-type
formEntries.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "my-tag"));
// more
UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formEntries);
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
```

Comment: you can see my answer,
and tell me what I should do

Comment: @Yanni Don't post for clarifications as an answer. Edit your question and add **all** relevant details to it.

Comment: Httpresponsedoes not have the method getErrorStream()
how can'i get this information

Comment: @Yanni Oops, I mixed up the libraries. Just get the response entity and check its content.

Comment: ContentType=null  
 and    ContenetEncoding=null

Comment: @yanni What are you trying to say with that? Is that the content of the response body?

Comment: I did : response.getEntity().getContent()
and i check the content

Comment: @yanno `getContent` returns an `InputStream`? Was the `InputStream` empty? If it's empty, then there's not much we can do. Anyway, a 500 error is a server error. You'll have to check what happened on the server.

Comment: [{"error":"bad_request","error_description":"malformed Json : Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1"}]